# Should we merge all the "Is X a Timelord" questions together?

Tags: discussion, repeated-questions

Gilles made a [comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/can-we-please-merge-all-alternative-power-source-in-the-matrix-questions-into/1577#comment3455_1577):

> Good idea, let's merge the timelord questions as well

I'm posting it as a Meta question, to see if there's support for the idea.

The rationale is similar to " [Can we please merge all 'alternative power source' in the matrix questions into one?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/can-we-please-merge-all-alternative-power-source-in-the-matrix-questions-into/1577) "

Comment: Or just close them. They're silly.

Comment: @Wikis - small steps... small steps...